# Indices of intersection between arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a fast way to compare every element of an array against every element in a list of unique identifiers?

Using a for loop to loop through each of the unique values works but is way too slow to be usable. I have been searching for a vectorized solution but have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
arrStart = []
startRavel = startInforce['pol_id'].ravel()
for policy in unique_policies:
    arrStart.append(np.argwhere(startRavel == policy))
```

**Sample Input:**

```
startRavel = [1,2,2,2,3,3]

unique_policies = [1,2,3]
```

**Sample Output:**

```
arrStart = [[0], [1,2,3],[4,5]]
```

The new array would have the same length as the unique values array but each element would be a list of all of the rows that match that unique value in the large array.

Comment: Are you looking for a dict? Maybe defaultdict(list)?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I am just trying to speed up this code since right now it is taking 10+ hours because of the size of data set. I think I need to find a way to not rely on a for loop

Comment: You could use a set instead of a list.

Comment: If you can sort on pol_id in the numpy query, you can probably just loop through the resultset once. If you want a non-numpy data structure, I would append them into a defaultdict(list) with pol_id as the key. But doing it in numpy will probably be better as it can let the database engine do some work. (and I don't use numpy so I can't post an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
import numpy as np
startRavel = np.array([1,2,2,2,3,3])
unique_policies = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Sort `startRavel` using [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

```
ix = np.argsort(startRavel)
s_startRavel = startRavel[ix]
```

Use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the indices in which `unique_policies` should be inserted in `startRavel` to mantain order:

```
s_ix = np.searchsorted(s_startRavel, unique_policies)
# array([0, 1, 4])
```

And then use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to split the array using the obtained indices. [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is used again on `s_ix` to deal with non-sorted inputs:

```
ix_r = np.argsort(s_ix)
ixs = np.split(ix, s_ix[ix_r][1:])
np.array(ixs)[ix_r]
# [array([0]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])]
```

---

**General solution** :

Lets wrap it all up in a function:

```
def ix_intersection(x, y):
    """
    Finds the indices where each unique
    value in x is found in y.
    Both x and y must be numpy arrays.
    ----------
    x: np.array
       Must contain unique values. 
       Values in x are assumed to be in y.
    y: np.array

    Returns
    -------
    Array of arrays. Each array contains the indices where a
    value in x is found in y
    """
    ix_y = np.argsort(y)
    s = np.searchsorted(y[ix_y], x)
    ix_r = np.argsort(s)
    ixs = np.split(ix_y, s[ix_r][1:])
    return np.array(ixs)[ix_r]
```

---

**Other examples**

Lets try with the following arrays:

```
startRavel = np.array([1,3,3,2,2,2])
unique_policies = np.array([1,2,3])

ix_intersection(unique_policies, startRavel)
# array([array([0]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([1, 2])])
```

Another example, this time with non-sorted inputs:

```
startRavel = np.array([1,3,3,2,2,2,5])
unique_policies = np.array([1,2,5,3])

ix_intersection(unique_policies, startRavel)
# array([array([0]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6]), array([1, 2])])
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been failing at this for hours, thank you so much! Great answer and explanation!